# Type mismatch. Required: Alignment.Horizontal Found: Alignment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button

## Context

I'm trying to create a FloatingActionButton at the bottom right part of a screen that allows you to scroll back up to the top of the screen (It's a screen with a scrollable list)

## Code

```
FloatingActionButton(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                        .navigationBarsPadding()
                        .padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                    onClick = { coroutineScope.launch { listState.scrollToItem(0) } }) {
                    Text(text = "Up!")
                }
```

I get an error  on `.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)`

> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> Alignment.Horizontal
> Found:
> Alignment

I get this means the .align method expects Alignment.Horizontal type but BottomEnd is  of type Alignment. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Alignment.BottomEnd` the `FloatingActionButton` must be in Box scope.

Use scaffold with floatingActionButton parameter instead it will place the button automatically in bottom right, like this:

```
Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton  = {
    FloatingActionButton()
  }
)
```

If you wanna change the place use `floatingActionButtonPosition`

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this codelab:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#8

Then you probably missed this line:

```
Box(Modifier.weight(1f))
```